# array python split str (too many values to unpack)

Tags: python, pandas

Array python split str (too many values to unpack)

```
df.timestamp[1]
Out[191]:
'2016-01-01 00:02:16' 
#i need to slept these into to feature 
split1,split2=df.timestamp.str.split(' ')

Out[192]:
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-216-bbe8e968766f> in <module>()
----> 1 split1,split2=df.timestamp.str.split(' ')

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Do it line by line first. Why do you rush?

Comment: What do you get from `print(df.timestamp.str)`?

Comment: `df.timestamp.str.split(' ')` what do you think this code is doing?

Comment: @ElisByberi i expect this split1= 2016-01-01 ,split2 = 00:02:16

Comment: @roganjosh output : <pandas.core.strings.StringMethods object at 0x000000001AADDE48>

Comment: @ElisByberi split when it see the plank

Answer (score 1):

Use the `str[index]` since you are splitting the series, the output will also be a  series and not two different lists in pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2016-01-01 00:02:16','2016-01-01 00:02:16'] })

split1,split2  = df.timestamp.str.split(' ')[0], df.timestamp.str.split(' ')[1]
```

`str.split` will return a series for example

```
df.timestamp.str.split(' ')

0    [2016-01-01, 00:02:16]
1    [2016-01-01, 00:02:16]
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```

Comment: i want just the time on variable for example the out that i expect >> split1 = 2016-01-01 and the split2 = 00:02:16

Comment: i expect this 

split1= 2016-01-01 ,split2  = 00:02:16

Comment: in this sample just 45

Comment: Then the suggested method is the way to go if you want them as a list then use...[0].values.tolist()

Comment: i try that there is no split (method or function) in list

Comment: Maybe all you wanted was `split1,split2 = df.timestamp[1].split(' ')`, what I have provided is a pandas answer

Comment: @Bharath Merged `split1,split2 = df.timestamp[1].split(' ')` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `split()` method wrong.

Given this:

```
df.timestamp[1]
Out[191]:
'2016-01-01 00:02:16'
```

Use `split()` method like this:

```
# I need to split timestamp[1]
split1, split2 = df.timestamp[1].split(' ')  # remove str.
```

Comment: Code `split1,split2 = df.timestamp[1].split(' ')`  from [Bharath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4800652/bharath)